# Memory deallocation in linux c++?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, malloc, free

In my application I allocated memory for my variable (`unsigned char*`) using `malloc()`, when try to deallocate that memory in destructor I use this condition to avoid double corruption.

```
unsigned char *wsqData;
wsqData= (unsigned  char *)malloc( 10000*sizeof( unsigned char));
```

in my destructor

```
  if(wsqData!=NULL)
  {
      free(wsqData);
      wsqData=NULL;
  }
```

now the problem is when I freed the memory before my destructor,this "if condition " could not working properly ,it once again try to free that variable it cause double corruption error. What is the problem in this scenario?

Comment: Why are you using C memory management in what is supposedly a C++ program ?

Comment: If you are trying to free something twice, then you have a bug in your code.  You haven't shown your code, so it's difficult to advise...

Comment: Why are you freeing the memory in different locations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `free` on the memory doesn't automatically set your pointer to `NULL`, so your condition is pointless. You need to set `wsqData` to `NULL` wherever you free it.

Of course the condition is pointless anyway, since calling free on a `NULL` pointer is guaranteed to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to set `wsqData` to `NULL` at the point when you free the memory outside of destructor. But in C++ you should use `new` and `delete`. And try to avoid freeing memory anywhere except in the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

As others denoted, you also need to set to NULL each time you free it. Make it a function - free the var then set it to NULL, and call it from both the destructor and any place in the program.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: This is a classic example of a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). You would need to set `wsqData` to `NULL` as suggested.